# Is it possible to create a new Google BigQuery table from pandas?

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a new bigquery table from pandas.  I don't see it in the documentation, so I'm guessing not.  But absence of evidence, etc., so I thought I'd ask.  And if it is possible, I'd love to see an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been added in 0.17, which should be released before too long here.  See release note [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#google-bigquery-enhancements).

If you're using conda you could upgrade to the release candidate like this:

```
conda install -c pandas pandas
```

Comment: Fantastic -- I should have checked the deb branch.  Is there anything pandas can't do? (not a real question, but it is ridiculously extendable!)

Answer (score 0):

as an option: you always can create [empty] table by providing select statement with dummy data of needed datatype and with aliases of needed filed names with extra where clause and proper disposition - destination table and write if empty for example

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM (
  SELECT 1 as col1, 'b' as col2, true as col3
)
WHERE false
```

Comment: Thanks for this -- I'll 0.17, but this is nice, too.